# Why is wstring_convert throwing a range_error?

Tags: c++, c++11, locale, wstring

I'm writing some code that needs to convert between byte strings and wide strings, using the system locale.  When reading from a file, this is incredibly easy to do.  I can use `std::wifstream`, imbue it with `std::locale("")`, and then just use `std::getline`.

According to cppreference's [codecvt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) page, `wifstream` just uses `codecvt<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t>`, so I thought that I might be able to convert between `std::string` and `std::wstring` by using that as well:

```
// utility wrapper to adapt locale-bound facets for wstring/wbuffer
convert
template<class Facet>
struct deletable_facet : Facet
{
    template<class ...Args>
    deletable_facet(Args&& ...args) : Facet(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
    ~deletable_facet() {}
};

std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
std::wstring_convert<
    deletable_facet<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>>> wconv;
std::wstring wstr = wconv.from_bytes(data);
```

However, when I try to run this, I get an `range_error` thrown from `wstring_convert`.  I did some googling around, and apparently this is what happens when `wstring_convert` fails to convert the string.

However, these strings are clearly perfectly able to be converted using `wfstream`, which should be using the same `codecvt` as I am using with `wstring_convert`.  So why does `wifstream` work, but `wstring_convert` not?

And is there a way that can I convert between `string`s and `wstring`s using the system's locale?

A full example of my problem, adapted from the [codecvt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) page, is [here](http://pastebin.com/1Yn7pz1X), and the output is:

```
sizeof(char32_t) = 4
sizeof(wchar_t)  = 4
The UTF-8 file contains the following UCS4 code points: 
U+007a
U+00df
U+6c34
U+1f34c
The UTF-8 string contains the following UCS4 code points: 
U+007a
U+00df
U+6c34
U+1f34c
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::range_error'
  what():  wstring_convert
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your`wifstream` and `wstring_convert` are using different facets.

`wifstream` is using a locale-dependent conversion facet; it pulls it out of `std::locale("")`, with which it was imbued, via `std::use_facet`

`wstring_convert` was given a locale-independent, standalone codecvt facet, and the one provided by your implementation apparently does not convert UTF-8 into anything fitting; try calling [in](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt/in) on it directly to see what it does.

An easy way to get a locale-dependent facet is to ask for it by name, as in 
[std::codecvt_byname](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_byname)

Comment: Thanks!  Fixed by replacing the wstring_convert definition with:

 `typedef deletable_facet<std::codecvt_byname<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>> local_facet_t; std::wstring_convert<local_facet_t> wconv(new local_facet_t(""));`